# ValueChangeEvent getOldValue() is null

Tags: java, jsf

I have the following method in my bean

```
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event){

        oldValue = (String) event.getOldValue();
        newvalue = (String) event.getNewValue();

 logger.info("values " + oldValue + " to " + newvalue );
```

And in my JSF

```
 <h:selectOneListbox size="1" 
 value="#{bean.Emp}"   onchange="this.form.submit()"
 valueChangeListener="#{bean.valueChange}
```

I could see that `oldValue` is always null, what could be the reason for this?

My JSF version is 1.1 and page scope is `request`.

Thanks

*Update 1*

Backing Bean

```
public class EmpBackingBean {

    private String selectedItemEmp;

    public void selectedItemEmp(String selectedItemEmp) {
        this.selectedItemEmp= selectedItemEmp;
    }

    public String getSelectedItemEmp() {
        return selectedItemEmp;
    }
```

Managed Bean

```
    EmpBackingBean empBackingBean = new EmpBackingBean();


    public EmpBackingBean getVehDetBackingBean() {
        return empBackingBean ;
    }

public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event){

        oldValue = (String) event.getOldValue();
        newvalue = (String) event.getNewValue();

logger.info("values " + oldValue + " to " + newvalue );

}
```

Comment: can you check that, your valueChange event is executing or not?

Comment: Yes it does execute. `logger.info("values " + oldValue + " to " + newvalue );` is comin from  `public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event){` and besides I could see values from `event.getNewValue()` regards

Comment: The onchange event might be the reason. What happens if you submit the form manually e.g. with a commandButton?

Comment: I tried removing `onchange` and tried with `commandButton`, however `oldValue` is `null` and `newValue` is displayed correctly with proepr values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML form does not submit the last rendered form values if that is what you are expecting.

```
public class Bean {
  private Object emp;
  public Object getEmp() { return emp; }
  public void setEmp(Object emp) { this.emp = emp; }
}
```

The old value is the value in "bean" when the form is submitted. If "bean" is request scope, a new instance will be created every time. I am guessing "Emp" is not initialized, so it will be null.

Comment: I have initialized like the following    `public void setSelectedItemEmp(String selectedItemEmp) {
        this.selectedItemEmp = selectedItemEmp;
    }` or I am still missing something?

Comment: The setter would generally only be called when the form is submitted (unless you're doing it in some other logic.) When the form is submitted, it tries to resolve `bean` to update the `emp` property. `bean` is request scope, so wasn't kept from the last request. A new instance is created and placed into scope. The getter is called and returns null. The `ValueChangeEvent` is created with the old value (null) and the new incoming value. _I'm making some assumptions here, but you haven't provided much code._

Comment: I have added my code above as update 1. Without changing scope and not changing onChange is it possible to get oldValue?

Comment: @Polappan: You need to realize that the old value does not come from the HTML. The old value comes from the backing bean. JSF calls its getter to get the initial value right before setting the submitted value. However, a request scoped bean is recreated on every single request so the properties are reinitialized to default. That's why you always get `null`. Use the JSF 2 view scope or Tomahawk's `t:saveState` to simulate it in JSF 1.

Comment: @BalusC How can I use `t:saveState` for getting previously selected value?

Comment: @Polappan: Just reference the whole bean by it. It will then behave like the JSF 2 view scoped bean.

Comment: @BalusC By adding `t:saveState`, does this cause any issues with existing code for `session` because I am getting an exception in this line `session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);`

Answer (score -1):

The following is a stripped down version of a code I wrote previously that did the trick :

```
public void valeurChangeeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {

    PhaseId phase = event.getPhaseId(); 

    if (!phase.equals(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION)) {    
        oldValue = yourBean.getYourValue();
        event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
        event.queue();
    } else {
        newValue = yourBean.getYourValue();
    }
}
```

Of course, as stated by others, the scope of yourBean must be longer than requestScoped.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a clumsy approach. Just use `event.getOldValue()` and `event.getNewValue()`.